# My font shorthand doesn't work, which include font-size and font-weight properities

Tags: html, css, frontend, font-size, shorthand

in my code, i use

```
{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

to set font, but when i switch this to font shorthand, like this `{font: 100 2.5rem}`
it seems doesn't work, my font style change to default.

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uj6jB.png)
it seems i have followed the shorthand rule for font, Any one can help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `font` shorthand property requires `font-size` and `font-family` to be specified. The `line-height` and the other `font-*` properties are optional.

[Reference.](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#font-shorthand)

Answer (score -1):

Font-weight defines from thin to thick characters.**100-400** is the same as normal, and **700-900** is the same as bold. After giving Font-weight you need to give the font-family property. If you don't want to use any font-family, then just put the font-family as none. This works for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  p.a {
    font: 100 2.5rem none;
  }
  p.b {
    font: 400 2.5rem none;
  }
  p.c {
    font: 700 2.5rem arial, sans-serif;
  }
  p.d {
    font: 800 2.5rem Georgia, serif;
  }
  p.e {
    font: 900 2.5rem normal;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>The font Property</h1>

  <p class="a">This is a paragraph. The font size is set to 10 pixels.</p>

  <p class="b">This is a paragraph. The font size is set to 10 pixels.</p>

  <p class="c">This is a paragraph. The font size is set to 10 pixels.</p>

  <p class="d">This is a paragraph. The font size is set to 10 pixels.</p>

  <p class="e">This is a paragraph. The font size is set to 10 pixels.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No. 100-400 aren't the same and 700-900 aren't the same.  When a specified weight is not available for the specified font-family, rounding occurs. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-weight

Comment: Hi @Kravimir, You didn't got my point. I am just saying that for font-weight 100,200,300,400 are the same as normal font-weight and 700,800,900 are the same as bold font-weight. That means for normal font-weight we can use 100,200,300,400 as font-weight and for bold font-weight we can use 700,800,900 as font-wight.

Comment: If it's working for you then you can consider my answer as correct and give me point. @ShendanTang

Comment: @MakdiaHussain /If/ I misunderstood your point, then I still don't understand your point.